# how to create single page website in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I am making a single page website in Laravel 5.6.
My site has 7 different sections. I am planning to make a CRUD operation for each section separately for Admin to make changes. 
However, I am stuck with how to load/Display information stored in different tables in one view(index.blade.php)? I have made multiple page sites in Laravel before but one page site is giving me some confusion. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally a single page website takes static content, you could just do static html and you'd be fine. your page would load faster.

but since you want to add crud to it, you can do a section model and page model

Then, do one to many relationships. page belongsToMany section.

then load the page with its sections on your view.

or

you can install voyager and make each section a setting on your site.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_UnIDIwT95NureFNedKN9_GA6UOiS2ox

Comment: Thanks @celso Ricardo I am trying to adapt this approach

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supoort the Vue.js

So, you can install modules of vue with npm

if you see the below src, you can see Vue component initialized when you installed laravel
'/resources/assets/js'

if you want to develop SPA web page, i will show you a guide line with vue.js + Laravel